# Akash verses Earth verses

Tags: scripture, shiva, vishnu, shaivism, conciousness

Are there aNY verses present in Yajur or Sama or Atharvana verses on Akasha mainly or earth?, not Rig
appreciate your response

Comment: There are many mantras in the Atharva Veda that have deity as Earth. Earth meaning Prithivi and not the element though. I have quoted few of those mantras here :https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38529/4732