# Who is the god of soil?

Tags: vedas, gods, vedic-gods

Who is the god of soil in Hinduism? What is the name of the god of soil in Vedas or Puranas or in any other Hindu scriptures?

Comment: Earth (Prithivi) is a Vedic deity .. there are many suktas dedicated to her in the Vedas (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/38528/4732)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which scripture is the earth first personified as a female deity?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38528/in-which-scripture-is-the-earth-first-personified-as-a-female-deity)